# Conversion of binary encoded unsigned char to integer

Tags: c++, binary, char

In the following, I encode the number 15 in binary into an unsigned char, and then convert it to an int. However, when I replace int with int8_t, it doesn't output 15 any more. I don't understand why though. Isn't the size of int8_t 8 bits, and so it should match pretty well with char, which is also 8 bits?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

  unsigned char binValue = 0<<7 | 0<<6 | 0<<5 | 0<<4 | 1<<3 | 1<<2 | 1<<1 | 1<<0; // this is 15 in binary

  int intValue  = (int)binValue;

  // memcpy(&intValue,&binValue,sizeof(int)); // Or this one

  std::cout << intValue << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int8_t` is signed. Try `uint8_t`. What do you mean by "stops working" ?

Comment: BTW this looks a lot like C++

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sorry. I meant the output is no longer 15 as expected. The program still compiles and runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see (actually what you don't see) is that `cout`, when feeded witn an `int8_t`, interprets the value as a character, and ASCII-code 15 might not leave anything visible on the debug console. Note that an environment (for example mine) might define `int8_t` as follows:

```
// _int8_t.h:
#ifndef _INT8_T
#define _INT8_T
typedef __signed char       int8_t;
#endif /* _INT8_T */
```

If you changed your `binValue` to, for example, `47`, then you would see an `'/'`.
To print a character type (or `int8_t`) as decimal, convert it to an int in the course of printing:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char binValue = 0<<7 | 0<<6 | 1<<5 | 0<<4 | 1<<3 | 1<<2 | 1<<1 | 1<<0;
    // changed to 47 for demonstration purpose

    int8_t intValue  = (int8_t)binValue;

    std::cout << "as char:" << intValue << std::endl;
    std::cout << "as decimal:" << (int)intValue << std::endl;
    std::cout << "as decimal:" << +intValue << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```